# Unable to get the desired result after loading data in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am not able to get the `genre` column values displayed while I am loading the data as below:

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale 1995)::Comedy|Drama
5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
7::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
```

I have tried creating the table as DDl:-

`create table movie(movie_id int, movie_name string , genre string) row format delimited fields terminated by '::';`

And

`create table movie(movie_id int, movie_name string , genre array<string>) row format delimited fields terminated by '::' collection items terminated by '|';`

But still the genre column is coming as blank.

Please help in creating the table correctly so as to place the data and get the desired result.

Output is-

`hive> select * from movie;`

```
OK
1               Toy Story (1995)
2               Jumanji (1995)
3               Grumpier Old Men (1995)
4               Waiting to Exhale 1995)
5               Father of the Bride Part II (1995)
6               Heat (1995)
7               Sabrina (1995)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Multi delimiter SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MultiDelimitSerDe)

P.s.
You might want to consider loading `genre` as `array<string>` instead of `string`

```
create external table movie
(
    movie_id    int
   ,movie_name  string 
   ,genre       array<string>
) 
    row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
    with serdeproperties 
    (
        "field.delim"       = "::"
       ,"collection.delim"  = "|"
    )
;
```

---

```
select * from movie
;
```

---

```
+----------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| movie_id |             movie_name             |                genre                 |
+----------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|        1 | Toy Story (1995)                   | ["Animation","Children's","Comedy"]  |
|        2 | Jumanji (1995)                     | ["Adventure","Children's","Fantasy"] |
|        3 | Grumpier Old Men (1995)            | ["Comedy","Romance"]                 |
|        4 | Waiting to Exhale 1995)            | ["Comedy","Drama"]                   |
|        5 | Father of the Bride Part II (1995) | ["Comedy"]                           |
|        6 | Heat (1995)                        | ["Action","Crime","Thriller"]        |
|        7 | Sabrina (1995)                     | ["Comedy","Romance"]                 |
+----------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```